# Is there a way to delete a file from a Windows server via FTP using GitHub actions?

Tags: github, iis, github-actions

I have [a GitHub `.yml` file](https://github.com/MrYossu/Pixata.Utilities/blob/master/.github/workflows/release.yml) to build and deploy my code. One of the projects in the solution is an ASP.NET Blazor web site.

The problem I have is that IIS locks some files, and the only way to deploy is to stop the site. This can be done by uploading a file named `app_offline.htm`, which tells IIS to stop the site and serve that file instead of any other content. When the deploy is done, this file can be deleted, and IIS restarts the site. I would like to do all of this in the GitHub action.

I have all of the steps working except for the last one. I can upload an `app_offline.htm` file to the server, then upload the site files, but I can't find a way to delete `app_offline.htm` afterwards.

If it would work, it would be even better to rename the file, rather than delete it, as that way I can leave the file there and just rename it as necessary.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the Windows VM that is spun up when you use `windows_latest` in an action include python, and python has FTP built-in.

Rather than upload and then delete a file, it was easier to leave one there and just rename it.

So, I created a "Site unavailable" static page named `_app_offline.htm` (note the `_` at the beginning of the file name) and uploaded it to the server. I then used the following steps to rename this to `app_offline.htm` (to tell IIS to stop the site), then upload the files, then another FTP step to rename it back again...

```
    - name: Rename _app_offline.htm to app_offline.htm to stop the site
      shell: python
      run: |
        import ftplib
        ftp = ftplib.FTP('${{ secrets.PIXATATESTFTPSERVER }}')
        ftp.login('${{ secrets.PIXATATESTFTPUSER }}', '${{ secrets.PIXATATESTFTPPASSWORD }}')
        ftp.rename('_app_offline.htm', 'app_offline.htm')
        ftp.quit()

    # step to deploy removed for clarity

    - name: Rename app_offline.htm back to _app_offline.htm to start the site
      shell: python
      run: |
        import ftplib
        ftp = ftplib.FTP('${{ secrets.PIXATATESTFTPSERVER }}')
        ftp.login('${{ secrets.PIXATATESTFTPUSER }}', '${{ secrets.PIXATATESTFTPPASSWORD }}')
        ftp.rename('app_offline.htm', '_app_offline.htm')
        ftp.quit()
```

If you do want to delete a file, you can do `ftp.delete('jim.txt')`.

Comment: You probably want to check if the file exists with `if '_app_offline.htm' in ftp.nlst() :`

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on github and never heard of using github to deploy applications to IIS.

I think the easiest way to rename a file can be achieved directly through the command line.

- Run the command line as an administrator and enter **ftp server IP or domain**
- Find the location of the file and use **[rename original file name modified file name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-rename)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess the question is, can I do this in a GitHub action? I'm quite new at them, so don't know them well enough to know what I can do in there. I guess if you can do ftp from a command line, you can probably do it in an action, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Ah, just discovered that the built-in Windows ftp command doesn't support passive mode, meaning that it's pretty useless nowadays. As github actions are run inside a VM, I can't rely on anything other than the built-in stuff, so unfortunately this wouldn't work. Thanks anyway.